# react router + jquery mobile page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, reactjs, react-router

I am working on single page application with ReactJS and react-router. There is also and jquery mobile. I don't want to use jquery mobile routing and I successfully disabled that feature.

My problem is that I want to have some transitions between the pages. Now I have big troubles with initializing each page with jquery mobile. Is there elegant approach of my case?

I appreciate any help.